# Android's in-app billing and bindService

Tags: android, binding, service, in-app-purchase

I am trying to implement in-app billing in my application based on [Sample Application](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-download).
But `bindService` always returns `false`.

Here is what I have.
**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<service android:name="tv.app.billing.BillingService" />
```

**Preferences.java** (need to start purchase from Preferences screen):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mBillingService = new BillingService();
    mBillingService.setContext(this); // tried to use getApplicationContext also
```

**BillingService.java**:
public class BillingService extends Service implements ServiceConnection {

```
/**
 * Binds to the MarketBillingService and returns true if the bind
 * succeeded.
 * @return true if the bind succeeded; false otherwise
 */
private boolean bindToMarketBillingService() {
    try {
        if (Debug.DEBUG) {
            Log.i(TAG, "binding to Market billing service");
        }
        boolean bindResult = bindService(
                new Intent(Consts.MARKET_BILLING_SERVICE_ACTION),
                this,  // ServiceConnection.
                Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        if (bindResult) {
            return true;
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not bind to service.");
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Security exception: " + e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

And in LogCat I see:

```
WARN/ActivityManager(48): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.vending.billing.MarketBillingService.BIND }: not found
```

What do I need to correct here?

Comment: Strange, but it doesn't work on emulator only and works on actual device. Probably, I should wait for the service to start?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, it can not be tested on the emulator (since it doesn't have Android Market?). 
[Testing In-app Billing](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_testing.html) section of official site says

> You cannot use the Android emulator to
>   test in-app billing

Answer (score 4):

You are right, the billing is not supported by the emulator, but you can use this test framework : [android-test-billing](http://code.google.com/p/android-test-billing) to test the In-App billing on the emulator.
This framework was used in the project Horer - [horaire de RER](http://www.horer.fr) to simplify the integration.

Answer (score 1):

Have you declared a reciever in your manifest ? ([source](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html))

```
    <receiver android:name="BillingReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.IN_APP_NOTIFY" />
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE" />
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Quote:

> In the sample application,
>   **BillingReceiver** is the
>   BroadcastReceiver that **handles
>   broadcast intents** from the Android
>   Market application and BillingService
>   is the Service that sends requests to
>   the Android Market application

Comment: Shame :-) also the `INTERNET` permission ?

Comment: Yes (however it is not required according to the sample app ;)

Answer (score 1):

Please put `bindToMarketBillingService()` in `onServiceConnected`.

Because when it finishes binding, it will call back and return `IBinder` to your connection.

I am 100% sure that this will work!

Comment: bindToMarketBillingService() where is method